# how to call external .js which is inside document.ready by passing in variables from html to call the .js file below

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to modify a  function I found online. its inside a document.ready function and if i try to use  function

```
functionName(variable1,... variableN){}
```

instade of

```
$(document).ready(function(){}
```

it fails. The code  by itself works  but I would  like to pass in variables to  do more stuff. Here is the  code and I would like to pass in  variable. Any help will be  highly appreciated

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".content-slider").slider({
    animate: true,
    change: handleSliderChange,
    slide: handleSliderSlide
  });
});

function handleSliderChange(e, ui)
{
  var maxScroll = $("#content-scroll").attr("scrollWidth") - $("#content-scroll").width();
  $("#content-scroll").animate({scrollLeft: ui.value * (maxScroll / 100) }, 1000);
}

function handleSliderSlide(e, ui)
{
  var maxScroll = $("#content-scroll").attr("scrollWidth") - $("#content-scroll").width();
  $("#content-scroll").attr({scrollLeft: ui.value * (maxScroll / 100) });
}
```

all the  functions above  are in one  .js file  and  I need to call it from html.
currently I call it in html like this:

```
<script src="slider_test.js" language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
```

but that way I cant  input variables

Comment: Please show us the code you tried. It's not clear what you are asking to do.

Answer (score 0):

You could put your variables in the global scope:

```
var theExtraThingINeed;

$(document).ready(function(){
  theExtraThingINeed = "someValue";

  $(".content-slider").slider({
    animate: true,
    change: handleSliderChange,
    slide: handleSliderSlide
  });
});

function handleSliderChange(e, ui)
{
  alert(theExtraThingINeed);

  var getHtmlStuff = $("#yourHtmlId").val();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. unfortunately the .js is external and I would  like the variable input from html. Oh, ofcourse, thanks. let me try  this

Comment: You can make the call inside the functions by putting `var getHtmlStuff = $("#yourHtmlId").val();` inside the `handleSliderChange`?

Answer (score 0):

That is because document ready literally says: "Wait for the document to be ready". Since you need the HTML from the document to do these operations. You can do the function call inside of the document ready and you'll probably be fine.

Comment: how would that be  done or  how can I replace document.ready with another function

Comment: Can you please explain the root of the problem in stead of the solution you're trying to implement? Maybe your solution doesn't fit your needs. Because I'm not sure if you have a timing or a scoping problem.

Comment: In the code  above, I want to pass in different IDs and CLASSES. so I wanted to say for example instade of $("#content-scroll") i will say $("#"+variableName). that way I can reuse the  function over  many  different IDs and  CLASSES

Answer (score 0):

Ok, my recommendation would be to write an object that handles this stuff. Its possible to do global functions but I don't consider this a good practice.

```
var plugins = {};
plugins.slider = function sliderPlugin(selector) {
   var $el = $(selector);

   $el.slider({
     change: function sliderChange(e, ui) {
       var maxScroll = $el.attr("scrollWidth") - $el.width();
       $el.attr({scrollLeft: ui.value * (maxScroll / 100) });
     },
     slide: function sliderSlide(selector, ui) {
       var maxScroll = $el.attr("scrollWidth") - $el.width();
       $el.attr({scrollLeft: ui.value * (maxScroll / 100) });
     }
   })
};
```

Also, since its the same function, its better to refactor a bit:

```
var plugins = {};
plugins.slider = function sliderPlugin(selector) {
   var $el = $(selector),
       handleSlider = function handleSlider(e, ui) {
           var maxScroll = $el.attr("scrollWidth") - $el.width();
           $el.attr({scrollLeft: ui.value * (maxScroll / 100) });
       };

   $el.slider({
     change: handleSlider,
     slide: handleSlider
   })
};
```

And call it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    plugins.slider('#content-slider');
    plugins.slider('.otherElement');
});
```